# проблема с дружественной функцией

Tags: c++, дружественная-функция, объявление

Я новичек в С++, объясните пожалуйста, почему не отрабатывает дружественная функция в main?
Имеется:

```
class myClass {
private:
    int i,j;
public:
    myClass();
    virtual ~myClass();
    friend void myFunc();
};
```

В main() такой код:

```
#include "myClass.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
myClass a;
myFunc();
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

В результате ошибка:

```
'myFunc' was not declared in this scope
```

Дико извиняюсь, заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, метка `объявление` по смыслу выглядит странно.

Comment: @Visman Плчему странно? Это относится к объявлению дружественных функций и видимости их объявлений.

Comment: @Visman Обратите внимание на само сообщение об ошибке. Оно как раз говорит об объявлении имени.

Answer (score 2):

Компилятор действительно не видит объявление функции, если она не объявлена вне класса, и не имеет место зависящий от аргумента поиск имени (**ADL - Argument-Dependent name Lookup**).

Поэтому объявите дружественную функцию также после определения класса.

```
class myClass {
private:
    int i,j;
public:
    myClass();
    virtual ~myClass();
    friend void myFunc();
};

void myFunc();
```

Сравните данные две демонстрационные программы.

```
#include <iostream>

class myClass {
private:
    int i,j;
public:
    myClass(){}
    virtual ~myClass(){}
    friend void myFunc() { std::cout << "Hi, I'm friend!" << std::endl; }
};

//void myFunc();
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

int main() 
{
    myFunc();

    return 0;
}
```

и

```
#include <iostream>

class myClass {
private:
    int i,j;
public:
    myClass(){}
    virtual ~myClass(){}
    friend void myFunc() { std::cout << "Hi, I'm friend!" << std::endl; }
};

void myFunc();
//^^^^^^^^^^^^

int main() 
{
    myFunc();

    return 0;
}
```

В первом случае возникнет ошибка компиляции, указывающая на то, что имя `myFunc` не объявлено. Во втором же случае программа успешно скомпилируется и выведет на консоль текст

```
Hi, I'm friend!
```

В первом случае когда компилятор встречает имя `myFunc`, то он ищет его в глобальном пространстве имен и не находит. Поэтому выдает диагностическое сообщение, аналогично показанном вами

> 'myFunc' was **not declared** in this scope

Если бы дружественная функция, объявленная в классе, имела аргумент, который имеет тип класса, то компилятор мог бы найти эту функцию, используя зависящий от аргумента поиск имени (ADL). Например,

```
#include <iostream>

class myClass {
private:
    int i,j;
public:
    myClass() : i( 10 ), j( 20 ){}
    virtual ~myClass(){}
    friend void myFunc( const myClass &c ) 
    { 
        std::cout << "Hi, I'm friend!" << std::endl; 
        std::cout << "You have i = " << c.i << " and j = " << c.j << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    myClass c;

    myFunc( c );

    return 0;
}
```

Данная программа успешно скомпилируется и выведет на консоль

```
Hi, I'm friend!
You have i = 10 and j = 20
```

Так как дружественная функция имеет параметр типа `const myClass &`, то, используя ADL, компилятор будет искать объявление дружественной функции также в классе `myClass`.

Зависящий от аргумента поиск имени (ADL) можно отключить, если заключить имя функции в скобки. Твк, например, ниже-приведенная программа не будет компилироваться в виду того, что имя функции заключено в круглые скобки, и ADL не будет применен к поиску имени функции.

```
#include <iostream>

class myClass {
private:
    int i,j;
public:
    myClass() : i( 10 ), j( 20 ){}
    virtual ~myClass(){}
    friend void myFunc( const myClass &c ) 
    { 
        std::cout << "Hi, I'm friend!" << std::endl; 
        std::cout << "You have i = " << c.i << " and j = " << c.j << std::endl;
    }
};


int main() 
{
    myClass c;

    ( myFunc )( c );

    return 0;
}
```